# How can I make to reference JAR libs on my project as externals?

Tags: java, web-applications

I'm working in a Web Project on Java using Eclipse.

This project will be deployed, at least, as "Develop" and "Testing" in two different WARs.

The project is working fine.

But when I Exported as a WAR file, each WAR have inside a copy of the libraries used (Spring JARs, Quartz JARs, Hibernate JARs, etc).

So I'm repeating the JARs on each implementation.

So the Idea of my Boss is remove the JARs from the web project and:

Option 1: Copy all the libraries to a windows folder and then reference with a "Relative Path".

Option 2: Put the JARs on Java JRE/JDK lib folder and the reference the JARs in some way.

Also with this change, we are trying to solve a PermGem Exception

What it is the best Idea?

I'm new with Java project, so I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for yours answers and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

IMO the *best* idea is to bundle them with your application.

If for no other reason, this allows you to upgrade a library in one version without affecting the others.

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding very well. You say that I have to keep each implementation with the Libraries inside? That allow to use diferent versions of libs in each Implementation, but that it is the oposite of what my Boos want. The idea is keep the Same Libs for each diferent implementation  to avoid problem of having diferent versions of a lib.

Comment: @MarkComix Then you'll have no way of deploying a test build with upgraded libraries. In any case, you should be using something that does your dependency management automatically (Maven, Ivy, Gradle, whatever) so you can't accidentally create an artifact with versions you don't intend.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your current approach is better, having jars packed with each war. As @Dave said, if you put them to a common place it will have dependency problems. 
Also both of your options will not solve `PermGen` error, to solve that as a temporary measure try to increase PermGen memory using `-XX:MaxPermSize` JVM argument, even after this if you still get the out of memory error then you need to dig out where the memory leak is.

Comment: Mmmmm, I don't know what to do. My Boss's Idea is remove all JARs from WebContext/Libs. But reading yours answers i'm lost. Also in some websites says that a good idea to solve Permgen exceptions is remove the libraries (JDBC for example) from the libs folder and move to jre/lib/ext/ folder.

Comment: @MarkComix Usually web container will load classes every time a war is deployed, hence two wars with same set of jars will be loaded twice, but as you said they are "Develop" and "Testing" so that should be ok. Either increase memory of put them at common location, but second approach(common location) should not be used in "Production" environment, if you get "PermGen" error in production also then you need to analyse for memory leak. Also how will you manage the wars for production system, as _italic_Dave_italic_ suggested use some dependency management system to avoid all such problems.